# How to get the differences of a file using SVNKit

Tags: svn, repository, diff, svnkit

I'm currently using SVNKit to be able to get the differences in code between my working copy, which I'm modifying, and the last version available in the subversion repository. I am currently using the doDiff method, however when the file contents are printed on the screen, the file residing in the respository is the one being displayed. the following is the information passed to the method.

```
client.doDiff(wc, SVNRevision.BASE, svnURL, 
    (SVNRevision.HEAD), SVNDepth.INFINITY, 
    true, System.out , null);
```

I can't understand why the changes are not being identified. Does maybe someone knows how to solve this problem, or maybe of another method which does get the differences between a working copy and the latest revision in the repository please?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

The [method signatures](http://svnkit.com/kb/javadoc/org/tmatesoft/svn/core/wc/SVNDiffClient.html) for doDiff all have 7 parameters, and I count 8 parameters in your example.

```
client.doDiff(wc, SVNRevision.BASE, svnURL, 
    (SVNRevision.HEAD), SVNDepth.INFINITY, 
    true, System.out , null);
```

wc has to point to the file, not the folder.

svnUrl has to point to the file, not the folder.

Comment: I managed to solve it... I think there has been a change in the parameters being used... the correct javadoc is [this](http://svnkit.com/javadoc/org/tmatesoft/svn/core/wc/SVNDiffClient.html)... Collections are added to the list of parameters